# Splitting a text into chunks (Javascript, regex)

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to split a text into several smaller chunks in order to parse it, using Javascript and RegEx. I have illustrated my best shot here, example included:

https://regex101.com/r/jfzTlr/1

I have a set of rules to follow: I would like to receive blocks. Every block starts with an asterics (*) as the first sign (if not indented, otherwise the tab), followed by 2-3 uppercase letters, a comma, a (possible) space and a code that could be A, R, T, RS or RSS. Followed by that is an optional dot. Linebreak afterwards, where the text comes. That text ends where the next asterics comes in, following the same pattern as above.

Could someone help me to figure out how to split this accordingly? This is my pattern so far:

```
[^\t](.{2,3}),\s?.{1,3}\.?\n.*
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/jfzTlr/8) work for you?

Comment: Very well, thank you. Very similar to further answers below, this works well, but there's another answer which gives me the possibility to group the items I need further on in my code. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're going with JavaScript, why not do it with a split which gives you the captured string to split on and the separated parts as well? Then bind the headings together in an array that looks like

```
[[heading1, block1], [heading2, block2], ...]
```

This way, you immediately have the data in a nice format to process down the line. Just an idea!

```js
const s = `*GW, A
This is my very first line. The asterics defines a new block, followed by the initials (2-3 chars), a comma, a (possible) space and a code that could be A, R, T, RS or RSS. Followed by that is an optional dot. Linebreak afterwards, where the text comes.

 *JP, R.
 New block here, as the line (kind of) starts with an asterics. Indentations with 4 spaces or a tab means that it is a second level thing only, that does not need to be stripped away necessarily.

 But as you can see, a block can be devided into several
    lines, 

    even with multiple lines.

 *GML, T.
 And so we continue...

    Let's just make sure that a line can start with an
    *asterics, without breaking the whole thing.
 *GW, RS
 Yet another block here.

  *GW, RSS.
  And a very final one.

        Spread over several lines.

*TA, RS.
First level all of a sudden again.
*PA, RSX
    Just a line to check whether RSX is a separate block.

`;
  
const splits = s.split(/\*([A-Z]{2,3}),\s?([AT]|RS{0,2})(\.?)\n/).slice(1);

const grouped = [];

for (let i = 0; i < splits.length; i += 4) {
  const group = splits.slice(i, i+3);
  group[3] = splits[i+3].trim().split(/\s*[\r\n]+\s*/g);
  grouped.push(group);
}

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: Very nice, especially as I need the found groups as well. Could you have a look at a few things? I tried but cannot really get this fully to work: 

a) make sure that the list of valid codes really work (A, R, T, RS or RSS). Now e.g RSX works, which is invalid.
b) capture the (possible) dot (after the code, before the linebreak.
c) Would it be possible to capture all lines within a block as themselves? So a block would consist of the initials, the code, a possible dot and an array of the lines that are following before the next asterics appears?

Comment: See my edit. I couldn't verify that RSX would result in a separate block. I added `*PA, RSX` at the bottom of the text and it doesn't lead to a new block. I also trimmed the white-space characters before and after text in lines. If you don't want that, get rid of `trim()`.

Comment: No problem. Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
^[ \t]*\*[A-Z]{2,3},\s*(?:[ART]|RSS?)\.?[\n\r](?:(?!^[ \t]*\*[A-Z]{2,3},\s*(?:[ART]|RSS?)\.?)[\s\S])+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/jfzTlr/6).

---

Broken into parts:

```
^[ \t]*\*[A-Z]{2,3}           # start of the line, spaces or tabs and 2-3 UPPERCASE letters
,\s*(?:[ART]|RSS?)\.?[\n\r]   # comma, space (optional), code, dot and newline
(?:                           # non-capturing group

    (?!^[ \t]*\*[A-Z]{2,3},\s*(?:[ART]|RSS?)\.?)   
                              # neg. lookahead with the same pattern as above
    [\s\S]                    # \s + \S = effectively matching every character
)+
```

The technique is called a tempered greedy token.

Comment: Thank you - almost as needed. It's a bit lose regarding the codes and does, as I noticed, not take care of the possible dot after the code. I forgot to mention that the grouping is a (very) nice thing to have, as suggested below. But again, thank you for your effort!

Comment: @chr_lt_ney: Updated, see the newly formed demo and regex (tighter now).

Comment: Wow, thanks! As I mentioned in a comment above: great work, but there's another answer which gives me the possibility to group the items I need further on in my code. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score -1):

Hope this is what you wanted. This works.

`([\*\t])+(.{2,3}),\s?.[A,R,T,RS,RSS]{1,3}\.?\n.*`

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get this to behave as I expected, try my regex101-link above and paste your code, does not take care of the whole block as expected.